# Can you put elements directly inside ng-view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-view

I am creating a slideshow in angularJS and want to change the link of the navigational arrows based on the templateUrl. I don't want to have to have arrows with unique urls in each template so I thought I could create one set and place it inside the ng-view and then just change the link based on what template/controller I am using. Is this possible?

HTML:

```
<div ng-view>

  <div class="dashNav">
    <a ng-show="prevValue" href="#/{{prev}}"><img src="images/prev-arrow@2x.png" width="18"></a>
    <a ng-show="nextValue" href="#/{{next}}"><img src="images/next-arrow@2x.png" width="18"></a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
angular
  .module('ciscoImaDashboardApp', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/welcome.html',
        controller: 'mainCtrl'
      });

  });


angular.module('ciscoImaDashboardApp')
.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.prevValue = false;
    $scope.nextValue = true;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use some sort of navigation service...

```
app.factory('navService', function() {
  var routes = {
    steps: [{
      id: 0,
      title: 'Home',
      route: '/',
      nextValue: true,
      prevValue: false,
      prevStep: null,
      nextStep: 'about'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'About',
      route: '/about',
      nextValue: true,
      prevValue: true,
      nextStep: 'contact',
      prevStep: ''
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Contact',
      route: '/contact',
      nextValue: false,
      prevValue: true,
      nextStep: null,
      prevStep: 'about'
    }]
  };

  return routes;
});
```

Then in your controller, for example's sake, you could do something like this...

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, navService, $location) {
  $scope.steps = navService.steps;
  $scope.prevValue = '';
  $scope.nextValue = '';
  $scope.prevStep = '';
  $scope.nextStep = '';
  $scope.route = '';

  $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function () {
    $scope.route = $location.path();
    for (var i=0; i<$scope.steps.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.route === $scope.steps[i].route) {
        $scope.prevValue = $scope.steps[i].prevValue;
        $scope.nextValue = $scope.steps[i].nextValue;
        $scope.prevStep = $scope.steps[i].prevStep;
        $scope.nextStep = $scope.steps[i].nextStep;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Then in your view...

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="dashNav">
      <a ng-show="prevValue" ng-href="#/{{prevStep}}"><img ng-src="{{prevImg}}">Prev</a>
      <a ng-show="nextValue" ng-href="#/{{nextStep}}"><img ng-src="{{nextImg}}">Next</a>
    </div>

    <ng-view></ng-view>

</body>
```

You can populate/store values, ng-href's, img sources, etc. through a service. In the Plunk below, I've stored the current route information in a service, and then I am sharing the information across each view's controller.

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ii1y8pSlOeXbJJmxNq3F?p=preview

Comment: Do you mind showing me an example? Like how can I make the "prevValue" falsy when I'm on the '/' route and truthy when I'm on the '/about' route?

Comment: @nehas I created a simple navigation service to give you a basic idea of what you can do (I updated my above post). You can even got simpler than that and update the service actions from controllers, etc. Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: this works great! But what's the point of the setCurrentRoute and getCurrentRoute? It works fine without it.

Comment: @nehas I was just showing how you can store information in a service dynamically. Probably a poor example, but I just wanted to give you an idea of the flexibility you can have.